# Video Capture (Composite Camera)

Tags: ros, video, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the easiest way to get composite video into ROS?  I'm talking about the cheap surveillance camera type stuff.  They sell USB adapters like this which I would like to use:
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B002H3BSCM/ref=oss_product?ie=UTF8&redirect=true](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002H3BSCM)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29836/video-capture-(composite-camera)/) by [691175002](https://answers.ros.org/users/1987/691175002/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-03-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As long as you have drivers that can convert the analog image into a digital version. Just write a simple node that uses the [image transport](http://ros.org/wiki/image_transport) capability of ROS and other ROS software can now access the image. It really isn't hard.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3